# How to propagate parent prop type check to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a conditional component that renders other part of my application only if a condition is met. In some cases I might need to pass the variable used by the conditional render component to some of this parent component children, but TypeScript doesn't know about it and it complains with an error.

Here's some code:

```
type AProps = {
  x: string
}
const A: FC<AProps> = ({x}) => {return (<>{x}</>)}

const B = () => {
  let x: string | undefined

  return (
    <ConditionalRender condition={!!x}>
      <A x={x} />
    </ConditionalRender>
  )
}
```

With this code snippet, I have a TS error on `x={X}`

[image]

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The thing here is that I have already checked that `X` exists on the `conditionalRender` parent component `... condition={!!x}>`

I would love to find a way to tell TS that the `X` prop was already checked and it is not undefined, because currently, with the example above, I would then have to do something like this inside the `ConditionalRender` component:

`{!!x && <A x={x} />}`

Comment: There may be a better solution to this, but to me it sounds like it's just a pitfall of using a conditional rendering component instead of an actual condition - although I see the appeal, I think I've done something similar before. I would just force it, since at this point you know about the type better than TS does - `<A x={x as string} />`

Comment: JSX isn't control flow and the element _does_ get created either way (just not rendered, presumably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `x` param from `ConditionalRender` to the `A` component, not from `B` where `x` can be `undefined`. Follow **React render design pattern** to do so.

```
type ConditionalRenderProps<T> = {
  params: T
  render: (x: NonNullable<T | null | undefined>) => ReactElement
}

const ConditionalRender = <T,>({ render, params }: ConditionalRenderProps<T>): ReactElement => {
  if (params === undefined || params === null) {
    return <></>
  }
  return <div>{render(params)}</div>
}



type AProps = {
  x: string
}
const A: FC<AProps> = ({ x }) => {
  return <>{x}</>
}

const B = (): ReactElement => {
  let x: string | undefined = "Hello"

  return (
    <ConditionalRender
      params={x}
      render={(params) => {
        return <A x={params} />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

---

React render design pattern:
https://javascriptpatterns.vercel.app/patterns/react-patterns/render-props