# React conditional wrapper and type narrowing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The usual React conditional wrapper, but written in TypeScript:

```
interface Props {
    condition: boolean;
    wrapper: (children: ReactNode) => ReactElement;
}

const ConditionalWrapper: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({ condition, wrapper, children }) =>
    condition ? wrapper(children) : <>{children}</>;
```

I would like to rewrite this component so that TypeScript type narrowing would work. Let me give you an example:

```
let tooltip: string | undefined;
...
<ConditionalWrapper
    condition={tooltip !== undefined}
    wrapper={(children) => (<Tooltip text={tooltip}>{children}</Tooltip>)}
>
    <span>We don't work</span>
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

The type of `tooltip` in `text={tooltip}` is still `string | undefined` but I would like it to be just `string` because the condition already narrows it as such.

I know I can use the *non-null assertion operator* like `text={tooltip!}` but we have strict ESLint code rules that don't allow this to avoid tricky bugs.

How do I rewrite the `ConditionalWrapper` component so that types will be narrowed as per the condition?

Comment: You're expecting `tooltip !== undefined` as the value for `condition` to narrow it _inside the `wrapper`callback_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to propagate parent prop type check to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780984/how-to-propagate-parent-prop-type-check-to-children)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well the other post doesn't answer exactly. The solution that question always checks for undefined/null check, but the condition can be an arbitrary boolean condition not necessarily checking null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rewriting:

```
interface Props {
   wrapper?: (children: ReactNode) => ReactElement; 
}

const ConditionalWrapper: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = 
({ wrapper, children }) => wrapper ? wrapper(children) : <>{children}</>;
```

and use it like this:

```
let tooltip: string | undefined;
...
<ConditionalWrapper
   wrapper={tooltip !== undefined ?
    (children) => (<Tooltip text={tooltip}>{children}</Tooltip>): tooltip
   }
>
  <span>We don't work</span> 
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, but even if it was adjusted to work, then what we'd need to provide for the wrapper is almost the same as if not using the component. Almost.